# Почему не срабатывает jQuery в мини-корзине Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с проблемой. В мини корзине Woocommerce нужно разместить функцию добавление/уменьшение. На мне фронт. Всего-то сделать вот такие фишки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я собственно говоря и сделал. Но вот поведение этих фишек крайне странное.

Допустим я зашел на сайт, корзина пустая, я добавил товар, товар добавился с помощу ajax без перезагрузки страницы. Я пытаюсь наживать на +/- а оно не реагирует. Такое ощущение будто этих элементов там просто нет поэтому jQuery их просто не обрабатывает. Но почему так и как поправить ситуацию? Подскажите пожалуйста. В консоли ошибок нет. Обратите внимание проблема не в бэкенде. В данном вопросе речь идет только об фронтенд части.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что корзина обновляется AJAX'ом. После того, как корзина обновляется, ваши елементы, к которым привязано событие заменяются другими. Поэтому решение следующее.

Сделайте для миникорзины обертку и привязывайте события так:

```
jQuery( '.my_wrapper' ).on( 'click, '.you-button', function() {
...
} );
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно.